# Whipped Cream out of Egg Whites

Tags: substitutions, eggs, egg-whites, whipped-cream

All types of fresh whipping cream or Half-and-Half that I have found have an ingredient called Carrageenan, which interacts really weird with my dad (makes him feel jittery).

As I was Whipping Egg whites the other day, I thought maybe I could use that as a substitute. Is there some way to cure egg whites so as to remove the possibility of salmonella, while not ruining the "stiff peaks" property so that I can add sugar and use it as whipped cream?

Can I add milk or something else to it to make the taste similar to that of real whipped cream?

Thanks for your ideas and time!

Comment: I think it would be more productive to look for carrageenan-free cream; meringues are nice and all, but they're no substitute for whipped cream. Have you checked in "health food" type stores? Or, if you live in or near farming country, you could check if there's a dairy near you with a "factory store".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carrageenan is a natural thickening agent. It helps the cream beat more easily and stay fluffy. I have seen brands that don't have it but I agree with Marti that you might have to try a health food store.

Egg whites do not beat to nearly the same consistency. They are much more foamy. If beaten all the way they are more stiff. If you are using the whipped cream on a pie you can make a meringue topping instead. It won't be the same but it will serve the same purpose.

Another alternative is to make whipped cream with evaporated milk:
[The first link from Google](http://www.southernplate.com/2013/10/how-to-make-whipped-cream-with-canned-evaporated-milk.html)

This technique produces cream that is similar to whipped cream- it has to stay chilled and be eaten right away. It will melt unless stabilized with gelatin.

Answer (score 0):

The basis of all whipped cream is simply the term of it..."whipped cream". You get heavy whipping cream, and beat the crap out of it until it thickens. Additional beatings will turn it into butter.

What gives whipped cream that iconic flavor profile is the additions of flavorings such as sugar and vanilla. Sure you can add thickening agents to it, but it isn't necessary if prepared right before consumption. Thickening agents are usually harmless commercial additives that aid in the mass production of the product. They may also aid in ensuring consistency in proportion to longevity when shipped and packaged.

**Recipe for whipped cream:**

Heavy Whipping Cream
Sugar and or Vanilla

1. Combine ingredients
2. Use muscle to whip it.. whip it good
3. Stop when it looks like whipped cream and eat it

Note--Whip it more for sweet butter. It's great on bread.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The op knows how to make whipped cream. He's looking for heavy cream that doesn't have carrageenan in it.

Comment: Not all heavy cream contains Carrageenan, especially if one has access to a grocer with organic products. One brand I know for sure is pasteurized Organic Valley cream. This is definitely supplied by Harris Teeter. Also, you can visit http://www.organicvalley.coop/products/cream/heavy-whipping-cream/ and enter a zipcode for a list. However, I do concede that my response was premptive upon further inspection. Apologies.

Comment: The downvote was not mine. The info in your comment about how to find carageenan free cream is a useful answer.